# Optimize Texture Lerp Job system

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to lerp between images using job system.
My method is simple, each textures is saved into base64 array and, on lerp:

- convert base64 to color32
- the job system lerp each color pixel from one texture to another
- result color32 write to texture then output to screen

But the Profiler's result look concerning to me.

I'm looking for tips and trick on optimizing multithreading. I'm new in the Job system and multithreading stuffs, so any guidance on optimizing this is very much appreciated.

[image]

Here are my code

```
public IEnumerator ScheduleLerpJob(byte[] byteFrom, byte[] byteTo, float duration, Action renderCallback)
    {
        var fromTexture = new Texture2D(textureSize, textureSize);
        
        fromTexture.LoadImage(byteFrom);
        fromTexture.Apply();
        
        var toTexture = new Texture2D(textureSize, textureSize);
        
        toTexture.LoadImage(byteTo);
        toTexture.Apply();
        
        var startPixels = new NativeArray<Color>(fromTexture.GetPixels(), Allocator.TempJob);
        var endPixels = new NativeArray<Color>(toTexture.GetPixels(), Allocator.TempJob);
        var resultPixels = new NativeArray<Color>(startPixels.Length, Allocator.TempJob);

        var elapsed = 0f;

        while (elapsed < duration)
        {
            elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            
            var lerpProgress = elapsed / duration;
            lerpProgress = Mathf.Clamp01(lerpProgress);

            var textureLerpJob = new TextureLerpJob
            {
                startPixels = startPixels,
                endPixels = endPixels,
                resultPixels = resultPixels,
                lerpProgress = lerpProgress
            };

            var lerpingJobHandle = textureLerpJob.Schedule(resultPixels.Length, 64);

            lerpingJobHandle.Complete(); // Wait for the job to complete

            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            
            var resultTexture = new Texture2D(fromTexture.width, fromTexture.height);

            resultTexture.SetPixels(resultPixels.ToArray());
            resultTexture.Apply();

            resultFrame = resultTexture;
            
            renderCallback.Invoke();
        }
        
        startPixels.Dispose();
        endPixels.Dispose();
        resultPixels.Dispose();
    }
```

The job:

```
struct TextureLerpJob : IJobParallelFor
{
    public NativeArray<Color> startPixels;
    public NativeArray<Color> endPixels;
    public NativeArray<Color> resultPixels;
    public float lerpProgress;

    public void Execute(int index)
    {
        resultPixels[index] = Color.Lerp(startPixels[index], endPixels[index], lerpProgress);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why create a new Texture each frame? Why not rather use `SetPixels` and reuse the same texture instance? Otherwise you will be leaking texture instances and fill the memory ... (Textures are only destroyed if you do so actively using `Destroy`) ... further you might want to use **Burst** and implement the lerp yourself (you can "steal" from the [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/79868d37d65d6efb5196aaf002f97a6f87b22f97/Runtime/Export/Math/Color.cs#L123) ;)) ... burst might be able to compile this better using floats rather then `Color`